# my fixed navbar width large than the screan width

Tags: html, css, frontend

I work in fixed nav bar width changing it's width to 100% on small-devices but the navbar going over the screen width.
as you see there on the image bellow:
[image]

the navbar css class

- parent base nav have display: block and position default
- the nav its's self position is fixed
- the tabs display fixed with warp;

css:

```
.edit-nav, .upgrade-nav {
border-radius: 15px;
width: 500px;
height: 52px;
position: fixed;
z-index: 1200;
}
.nav-tab-flex {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}
           
@media (max-width: 767px){
    .edit-nav {
         border-radius: 0;
         width: 100%;
         height: auto;
         text-align: center;
    }
    .nav-Section {
        display: block;
        height: 160px;
    }
    .account-nav {
        position: relative;
        right: 0;
    }
}
```

html code:

```
<div class="edit-nav bg-white shadow-sm p-2    ">
            <nav class="bg-white d-block d-md-none pb-2">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                    <span class="logo border rounded-pill">
                        <img src="../image/Logo.png">
                        <label class="hisstag">HISSTAG</label>
                    </span>
                    <span class="account-nav">
                        <img class="account-img border" src="../image/Logo.png">
                    </span>

                </div>
            </nav>
            <!-- start tabs section -->
            <nav class="nav-tab-flex">
                <span class="logo m-2 d-none d-md-block">
                    <img src="../image/Logo.png">
                </span>
                <a href="../En/EditProfile-en.aspx" class="bg-tab Profile">
                    <img src="../image/EditProfile.png">
                    Profile</a>
                <a href="../En/SocialMedia.aspx" class="bg-tab SocialMedia">
                    <img src="../image/EditSocial.png">
                    SocialMedia
                </a>
                <a href="../En/Link.aspx" class="bg-tab Link">
                    <img src="../image/EditLink.png">
                    Link
                </a>
                <a href="../En/Theme.aspx" class="bg-tab Theme">
                    <img src="../image/EditTheme.png">
                    Theme 
                </a>
            </nav>
      <!-- end tabs section -->
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue on the .row class in bootstrap add more margin which cuase the issue, so I set the margin right = 0;

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell with this amount of code but it could be that the elements in the div were told a width that is larger than the screen width causing it to spill over. Try removing widths from elements in the div and see if that helps.

Comment: yah in the first show it's lock like the issue form sub-elements width but in fact none of them have a static width, but even of that I tried to add a small width but nothing work. I will update the question with the full code , please check it again .